# Inequality of factors

Tags: inequality

I wonder if there is a way to prove this mathematically?$$1 – t^{2n} =(1 – t)(1+ t + t^{2} + . . . + t^{2n – 1}) < 2n(1 – t)$$ I can't understand how $$(1+ t + t^{2} + . . . + t^{2n – 1})$$ become less than $$2n?$$ ANy idea would be a great help! tnx!

Comment: What are $t$ and $n$? It fails for $n=0$, for example.

Comment: Is $t$ supposed to be small compared to $1$ ?

Comment: Some hypothesis is missing. Probably $-1< t<1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inequality is guaranteed to be true if we assume $n$ is a positive integer and $-1 < t < 1$.

If $n > 0$ is an integer and $-1 < t < 1$, then $1-t > 0$ and $|t|^{i-1} < 1$ for all $i = 1, 2, \ldots, 2n$. In case you are not familiar with the absolute value, it is defined by $\vert \cdot \vert: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$,
$$\vert x \vert = \begin{cases} x & \text{ when } x > 0\\ 0 & \text{ when } x = 0\\ -x & \text{ when } x < 0\end{cases}$$
which just ignore the negative sign of $x$ if $x < 0$. With these we see that
$$1+t+t^2+\ldots+t^{2n+1} \leq 1+\vert t \vert+\vert t \vert^2 + \ldots + \vert t \vert^{2n+1} = \sum_{i=1}^{2n} \vert t \vert^{i-1} < \sum_{i=1}^{2n} 1 = 2n$$
and therefore 
$$(1-t)[2n - (1+t+t^2+\ldots+t^{2n+1})] > 0$$
and finally
$$(1-t)2n > (1-t)(1+t+t^2+\ldots+t^{2n+1})$$

Note that you cannot conclude the final inequality from that $2n > 1+t+t^2+\ldots+t^{2n+1}$ if you do not have $1-t > 0$, as multiplying a negative number to both sides of an equality reverse the inequality sign.

Comment: wow! that's amazing proof! I cant believe there exist such proof... I thought its just  a rough estimation.. tnx sir!

Comment: Sir if it is not too much... will you consider this question?  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1313529/inequalities-of-the-product-of-sum-and-difference-of-two-terms

Answer (score 3):

Consider $$S=\sum_{i=0}^{2n-1}t^i=1+t+t^2+\cdots+t^{2n-1}$$ Each term is smaller than $1$ (I admit that the question implies $0<t<1$).

So, just count the number of terms in the summation to get $$S=\sum_{i=0}^{2n-1}t^i<\sum_{i=0}^{2n-1}1 ^i=2n$$

Comment: thankx sir for your answer neat and simple :)

Comment: @AirohBorbe. You are very welcome !

Comment: Sir if it is not too much... will you consider this question? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1313529/inequalities-of-the-product-of-sum-and-difference-of-two-terms