# inequalities of the product of sum and difference of two terms

Tags: inequality

I'm aware of the product of sum and difference of two terms but I'm poor in proving inequalities...all I can do is to verify the claim... please somebody help me...$$H(t) >\frac {t^{n–1} (1 + t)}{2}$$
$$1 - H^2(t)<[1-\frac{t^{n-1} (1+t)}{2}][1+\frac{t^{n-1} (1+t)}{2}]<  2 – t^{n-1} (1 + t)$$

How did this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put $a=H(t)$, $b=\frac {t^{n–1} (1 + t)}{2}$. Then we can rewrite the initial inequalities as $a>b$ and $1-a^2<(1-b)(1+b)<2-2b.$ The implication $a>b$ $\Rightarrow$ $1-a^2<(1-b)(1+b)=1-b^2$ holds, for instance, when $b\ge 0$.
The inequality $(1-b)(1+b)<2-2b$ holds for each real $b\ne 1$ because it is equivalent to an inequality $0<(b-1)^2$.

Comment: Sir is there a mathematical induction for this?

Comment: @AirohBorbe No, there is no need to use mathematical induction here.

Comment: got it! thanks a lot sir!!! :)